# Invoking an external REST API concurrently via AKKA in Java

Tags: java, rest, concurrency, akka

I am trying to 
*get the information of cars from Tesla Server through its API*

. And I want to do it concurrently .i.e *fetch the information of multiple cars in parallel using AKKA actors*

> My Approach:

**(1) First get the total number of cars.**

**(2) Create actors equal to the number of cars.**

**(3) Inside each actor call rest API to get the information of cars in parallel. i.e.each actor will be provided with url containing the car id.**

Am I doing it right regarding my approach?

Specifically, in point number 3, I have made call to the Tesla Server inside each actor using `AsyncHttpClient` from `com.ning`. Will using `AsyncHttpClient` inside each actor ensure that each actor will send request asynchronously to the server without blocking other actors?

Will provide further information if need be. I am beginner in AKKA. Looked a lot of threads but could not find exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for point number 3, as long as you use a `Future` based API in your actors, the actors will not block.

In general it is hard to tell much more about your approach without knowing why you chose to use one actor per car.

Consider this question: why couldn't you simply create a `listOfCars: List[String]` of URLs and use `Future.traverse(listOfCars)(downloadCarDataForUrl _)`?

Finally, I don't know how `AsyncHttpClient` behaves, but I would double check that if you have a list of thousands of cars, `AsyncHttpClient` will not concurrently download all of them... if that's the case, you risk being blocked quite quickly by the api provider. If this becomes a problem, you could look into akka-http which only uses a limit number of connection to a certain host.

Comment: My whole point in choosing 1 actor per vehicle was to fetch each vehicle data simultaneously from the server. But it seems that I could have done the same with a single actor using future based APIs. What is your suggestion in this? Which one do you think is a better approach?

Comment: I would not recommend using 1 actor per download if you don't do anything else with the actor afterwards. So if the only purpose is only a download, use the future based variant. Now, again, creating a single actor to handle all the downloads is not needed, but could make error handling easier to implement.

Comment: I want a add a little detail on what I am trying to do.. Not just download I am trying to trying to stream data of multiple cars continuously from the server in real time and continuously push the real time data into amazon kinesis... :)

Comment: I tried using AKKA Http as you suggested but kept of getting scala method/class not found exception...Could not figure it out for two days. so I finally resorted to this approach...

Comment: In that case actors are already more appropriate. Each actor can manage the state of 1 car, and take different actions based on events happening, ...